# React infinite scroll self implementation detect differently on different devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I implemented an infinite scroll on my App.
Each time the user scrolling to the bottom of the page more data is being loaded.
this is the function that triggers it:

```
if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.documentElement.scrollHeight)
```

It works great on my desktop widescreen, but for some reason on my laptop it works only if I change it to this:

```
if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop +1 >= 
                       document.documentElement.scrollHeight)
```

it's like it missed 1 pixel to get to the bottom of the page. I can't understand what can cause this?

Thanks

Comment: If possible create a jsfiddle and replicate the same issue there and share the link of that fiddle